# How to apply configuration changes of language portlet to all pages

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I add the language portlet in my liferay theme using this code:

```
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('portletSetupShowBorders', 'false'))
#set ($portlet_id = '82')
#set ($instance_id = "239abc678iuy")
#set ($my_portlet_id = "${portlet_id}_INSTANCE_${instance_id}")
$theme.runtime($my_portlet_id, "", $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
```

in the `portal_normal.vm`.

I use the same theme in many pages. The problem is when I change the configuration of the language portlet (e.g. add or delete some languages) the modification is only applied to the current page, not to other pages.

Comment: just i need to solve the problem of updating the changement of the protlet language in all the page

Comment: The instance id is useless, as the language portlet is not instancable.

Answer (score 0):

The preferences for the language portlet are *unique per layout*, that means every page has its own configuration for this portlet.

There is a setting in the `liferay-portlet.xml` which controls that. It defaults to `true`, thats why it isn't mentioned in the section for the language portlet.

You have two options:

1. Create an ext-plugin and redefine the language portlet in the `liferay-portlet-ext.xml`:

   ```
   <portlet>
       <portlet-name>82</portlet-name>
       <icon>/html/icons/language.png</icon>
       <struts-path>language</struts-path>
       <!-- ... copy of all other lines of portlet 82 from liferay-portlet.xml -->
       <preferences-unique-per-layout>false</preferences-unique-per-layout>
   </portlet>
   ```
2. Create a hook plugin and create a service wrapper for the PortletLocalService, that returns a custom wrapper for portlet 82, that in the end returns `false` for `preferencesUniquePerLayout`.